# SQL query to summarize data on daily basis

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I use following SQL query to get data from MySQL database.

```
select
    classid,start,
    count(case when classid='Handball' then 1 end) as handball_count
from signature where classid='Handball'
group by start
```

Date is for example `2016.12.01. 10:51:58` format.

It should be on a daily basis, so for example `2016.12.01. 10:51:58` and `2016.12.01. 15:51:58` shouldn't be a different entry in this query. How should I group by day? I would like to summarize participants  for each activity per day and not separated by the date of the participant's signature.

Comment: You could cast the datetime as a date.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server?  Also, those timestamps don't appear to be in any standard format.  What type are they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this

```
SELECT count(case when classid='Handball' then 1 end) as handball_count,
   classid,DATE(start) DateOnly 
FROM signature where classid='Handball'
GROUP BY DateOnly;
```

Answer (score 1):

please convert `datetime` to `date`

```
     SELECT CONVERT(date, date)
or
GROUP BY CAST(date AS DATE)


select
    classid,CONVERT(date, date),
    count(case when classid='Handball' then 1 end) as handball_count
from signature where classid='Handball'
group by date,classid
```

Answer (score 1):

I am considering `start` as your date field, so might be this can help you.

```
select
    classid,CONVERT(start, date),
    count(case when classid='Handball' then 1 end) as handball_count
from signature where classid='Handball'
group by start
```

Also your date format doesn't match with standard timestam so please take a look for that. Might be below reference can also help you.

[DATE_FORMAT(date,format)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

[MySQL: CONVERT](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/functions/convert.php)

[STR_TO_DATE()](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-str_to_date-function.php)